# What should I have done?

Tags: modal-verbs

In the following conversation, what does the boldface sentence mean? Does it imply something like this: I did something, but it didn't work out.

A: I was in a meeting at work when my girlfriend texted me saying she needed to see me right away. **What should I have done?**

B: You should've sent her a message and told her you'd call back her.

Answer (score 1):

It is just asking for advice.

They must have done something, even "sat still and ignored my phone" is doing *something*.  We don't know anything about what the person did. But since the person is asking for advice, they must believe that there is something better to have done than what they did.

Perhaps it didn't work out well.  Perhaps it was okay, but they think that there is something better that they could have done.